# RxJS — Group items by multiple conditions and process each group

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have set of emitted values (stock market transactions) with time and price and vol like this...

```
TIME      PRICE    VOL
13:45:01  12       1
13:45:01  12       1
13:45:01  12       10
13:45:01  13       1
13:45:01  13       3
13:45:02  13       1
```

And I just want to merge values within the same second and same value and accumulate VOL so the resulting observable will be emitting such values based on source above:

```
TIME      PRICE  ACCUMULATED VOL
13:45:01  12     12
13:45:01  13     4
13:45:02  13     1
```

This is some kind of grouping and then reducing. I'm reading documentation but can't figure out which operators to use...

Can somebody help?

Comment: what kind of stream is it? async or sync, can you show the intial stream

Comment: This is stock market transactions over time during the day for one share. The data are flowing in time order one by one sometimes very fast and I'm trying to accumulate/group some of them for further processing. The stream is flowing in real time exactly at the TIME provided in column.

Comment: This sounds like `scan()` operator but you want each row to be a separate emission?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `stockSource` is the realtime stream that push buy/sell item. You can use `scan` to accumulate your data and compute accumulation count there.

```
stockSource.pipe(scan((acc,curr)=>{
   const foundObj=acc.find(obj=>obj.PRICE===curr.PRICE);
   if(!foundObj){ return [...acc,curr]}
   foundObj.ACCUMULATED++;
   return acc
},[])).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

## A Custom Operator

I think there must be a better way to do this, but it didn't come to me, so I made a custom operator.

This might be overkill? No idea, You can try it out/ test it yourself if you're so inclined.

Note that for many operators, returning `from(thing)` is the same as returning `thing`. So when I return an array from concatMap, that array is turned into a stream for me.

```ts
function customOperator(){
  return s => defer(() => {
    let currentTime = "";
    let buffer = {};
    return s.pipe(
      concatMap(({time, price, vol}) => {
        let ret = [];

        if(currentTime != time){
          ret = Object.values(buffer);
          buffer = {}
        }

        let accumVol = buffer[price]?.accumulatedVol;
        accumVol = accumVol != null? accumVol : 0;
        buffer[price] = {
          time,
          price,
          accumulatedVol: accumVol + vol
        };
        currentTime = time;
        
        return ret;
      }),
      s => concat(s, defer(() => Object.values(buffer)))
    )
  })
}

function makeTransaction(time, price, vol){
  return ({time, price, vol});
}

of(
  makeTransaction("13:45:01", 12, 1),
  makeTransaction("13:45:01", 12, 1),
  makeTransaction("13:45:01", 12, 10),
  makeTransaction("13:45:01", 13, 1),
  makeTransaction("13:45:01", 13, 3),
  makeTransaction("13:45:02", 13, 1)
).pipe(
  customOperator()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your requirements, this looks like a job for `groupBy`:

1. Generate a key to group items by `time` *and* `price`
2. There will be one stream per set
3. Reduce each stream into a single reduced emission to accumulate all volumes
4. Merge back each stream into the output

```js
const transactions$ =
  of( {time: '13:45:01', price: 12, volume:  1}
    , {time: '13:45:01', price: 12, volume:  1}
    , {time: '13:45:01', price: 12, volume: 10}
    , {time: '13:45:01', price: 13, volume:  1}
    , {time: '13:45:01', price: 13, volume:  3}
    , {time: '13:45:02', price: 13, volume:  1});

const groups$ =
  transactions$.pipe( groupBy(t => `${t.price}@${t.time}`)
                    , mergeMap(group$ =>
                        group$.pipe(reduce((tt, {time, price, volume}) =>
                          ({time, price, volume: volume + tt.volume}),
                            {volume: 0}))));

groups$.subscribe(t => console.log(JSON.stringify(t)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.3.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-y3JTS47nnpKORJX8Jn1Rlm+QgRIIZHtu3hWxal0e81avPrqUH48yk+aCi+gprT0RMAcpYa0WCkapxe+bpBHD6g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const {of} = rxjs;
const {groupBy, mergeMap, reduce} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```